# DeploymentDescriptorLoadException in websphere 6

Tags: exception, web.xml, websphere-6.1

Hi the error Looks like this when I am deplying in ear in websphere 6 , I checked my web.xml It looks fine to me. please help

com.ibm.etools.j2ee.commonarchivecore.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: IWAE0022E Exception occurred loading deployment descriptor "WEB-INF/web.xml" for module "acs_nominal_roll_webapp.war" in EAR file "C:\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\default\wstemp\514564614\upload\nominal_roll-dev.ear"
[8/14/12 21:58:25:254 MDT] 0000002f SystemErr R com.ibm.etools.j2ee.commonarchivecore.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: IWAE0022E Exception occurred loading deployment descriptor "WEB-INF/web.xml" for module "acs_nominal_roll_webapp.war" in EAR file "C:\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\default\wstemp\514564614\upload\nominal_roll-dev.ear"
!Stack_trace_of_nested_exce!
com.ibm.etools.j2ee.commonarchivecore.exception.NoModuleFileException: A file does not exist for module element having uri: acs_nominal_roll_webapp.war

Comment: Check your ear's application.xml file.

Comment: As @dbreaux says, this almost certainly means you have an application.xml referring to a module that does not actually exist in the EAR.

Answer (score 1):

The EAR file might be corrupt or incomplete. Entry for the web project might be missing within Ear.